# Proper way to close NSDocument programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I have a subclass of NSDocument that crashes whenever I use [self close] to avoid the default 'save' dialog for new documents:

```
2013-02-25 15:23:06.338 MyApp[692:403] An uncaught exception was raised
2013-02-25 15:23:06.338 MyApp[692:403] NSWindow: -_newFirstResponderAfterResigining is not a valid message outside of a responder's implementation of -resignFirstResponder.
2013-02-25 15:23:06.356 MyApp[692:403] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b2cdf56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff88c00d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b2cdd8a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b2cdd14 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff858e0c34 -[NSWindow _newFirstResponderAfterResigning] + 164
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff85882c8a -[NSTextView(NSSharing) resignFirstResponder] + 54
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8536dd79 -[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:] + 429
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff85488dfb -[NSWindow dealloc] + 802
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8528b955 -[NSWindow release] + 535
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff858b541c __destroy_helper_block_4 + 26
10  libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x00007fff8702b174 _Block_release + 181
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff84ab28f2 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 308
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b262e7c __CFRunLoopRun + 1724
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b262486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d64e2bf RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d65556d ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d6553fa BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff85252779 _DPSNextEvent + 659
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8525207d -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8524e9b9 -[NSApplication run] + 470
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff854caeac NSApplicationMain + 867
21  MyApp                                0x00000001059098d2 main + 34
22  MyApp                                0x00000001059098a4 start + 52
23  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Has anyone seen this before or can anyone suggest a better/proper way to close an NSDocument without the save dialog being shown?

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to close a document directly here? Might prompt some ideas as to alternative routes, rather than directly attacking this crasher

Comment: Hi, Mike. The documents represent blog posts. A user opens a document and either saves it locally or posts to the server. In the majority of cases when they post without saving they don't want to be asked to save when they close the document, they would prefer the document just go away. Not a very big deal but it's a small point of friction that I've been asked about by some users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So judging by your followup comments, what you're trying to do is suppress the standard close confirmation sheet under specific circumstances. Some ways to do that:

- Adopt autosaving-in-place, which moves away from the ancient paradigm of manually saving documents
- Override `-[NSDocument canCloseDocumentWithDelegate:shouldCloseSelector:contextInfo:]` so it tells the delegate "yes, you can close", rather than presenting a sheet
- Once a post is made, call `[document updateChangeCount: NSChangeCleared]` to inform the document that you consider it to be saved

Comment: I've already got autosaving-in-place implemented, so I'll give the second and third suggestions a try. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. Even with autosave-in-place, if the user goes to close a document that's *never* been saved, the OS still throws up a sheet about it. So yeah, you need one of the other options for that :-)